JMS Serializer unknownObjects
I'm trying to modify a Object of my collection that it can handle unknown objects
I Got Objects A, B, C but it can also happen that I get an Object Z which I have no presentation in My RootElementObject for
class RootElementObject {
   #[JMS\SerializedName('A')]
   #[JMS\Type("App\DataObjects\A")]
   private ?A $a = null;

   #[JMS\SerializedName('B')]
   #[JMS\Type("App\DataObjects\B")]
   private ?B $b = null;

   #[JMS\SerializedName('C')]
   #[JMS\Type("App\DataObjects\C")]
   private ?C $c = null;
}

My XML :
<RootElementObject>
    <A>
        <Units>123</Units>
        [...]
    </A>
    <B>
        <Units>123</Units>
        [...]
    </B>
    <C>
        <Units>123</Units>
        [...]
    </C>
    </Z>
        <Units>123</Units>
        [...]
    </Z>
</RootElementObject>

I can anticipate what the value within the XML are but I need a way to have all Objects which are not yet known to me still being handled.
I expect or want an array or a collection something like that which contains then all unknown Elements from my XML.
